# Grabbing data off of PrimeNG datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm having a little bit of an issue with a feature I want to enable. When the user does a search it populates a table with the results. I want them to be able to delete that row the `"Delete"` button is on.

Here  is my table: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-UI/blob/58ba15188a490a9c867e0727e56c3efa0a9f6b1e/src/app/table/table.component.html#L21-L25

My `console.logs` do not show anything is grabbed from the table except for

```
 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 81, screenY: 615, clientX: 81, clientY: 524, …}
```

and my API is revealing a `null` on the object it should be receiving to delete. Any pointers on this? I'm a little lost and two hours of research was not fruitful for me it seems.

Thanks

Comment: You should not tag PrimeNG questions with primefaces. Please use the primeng tag. PrimeFaces is a JSF (component) library and is not related to PrimeNG.

Comment: My apologies,  didn’t know the difference between the two. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're passing in two arguments to the `onDelete($event, tech)` method in the template but only have one parameter defined in the component `onDelete(value: any)`. So the value is being set to the `$event` which in this case is a `MouseEvent` because the button is bound to the `click` event.

From the documentation [$event and event handling statements](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-and-event-handling-statements):

> The shape of the event object is determined by the target event. If the target event is a native DOM element event, then $event is a DOM event object, with properties such as target and target.value.

If you don't need the information from the `$event` object, remove it from the call to `onDelete()` in the template.

```
<p-column header="Action">
  <ng-template let-tech="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <button type="text" pButton label="Delete" (click)="onDelete(tech)"></button>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Then the `onDelete()` method in the component will get the value of the table row.

```
public onDelete(value: Tech) {
  console.log(value);
  this.tableService.deleteRegistrant(value)
    .subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log('[POST] create Registrant successfully', value);
      }, error => {
        console.log('FAIL to create Registrants!');
      },
      () => {
        console.log('POST Registrants - now completed.');
      });
  this.submitted = true;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, it seems to be grabbing the data just fine now!